# Unity IoC registers/resolves two classes with a interface and two types

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have `Calculator` to show results on console or window messagebox. 
There is no issue if I have one type for `IOutputService`.
Now, I have two types - `ConsoleOutputService` and `MessageBoxOutputService`.

How can I create/register two calculators with different types in constructor and use a calculator on runtime?

---

```
class Mockup
{
    void Bootstrapping()
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IInputService, ConsoleInputService>();
        container.RegisterType<IOutputService, ConsoleOutputService>("Console");
        container.RegisterType<IOutputService, MessageBoxOutputService>("Window");

        // expect with ConsoleOutputService
        --> Pseudo code container.RegisterType<ICalculator, Calculator>("Cal1");
        // expect with MessageBoxOutputService
        --> Pseudo code container.RegisterType<ICalculator, Calculator>("Cal2");**
    }

    void RunConsole()
    {
        ICalculator lp = container.Resolve<ICalculator>("Cal1");
        lp.Run();
    }

    void RunWindow()
    {
        ICalculator lp = container.Resolve<ICalculator>("Cal2");
        lp.Run();
    }
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public Calculator(IInputService inputService, IOutputService outputService)
    {
        InputService = inputService;
        OutputService = outputService;
    }
    public void Run()
    {            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you might want to reconsider your architecture. For example, how about waiting until you know what type of application you are before registering the output service. Then you could just register the one you need. Or you could add an extra layer of indirection, asking another service to get you the OutputService, and that could have knowledge of what mode your app is running in.

But what you asked to do is possible with unity. There are two approaches. First is to use an `InjectionConstructor` with two `ResolvedParameter`s - this lets you specify the named output service to use. However, it is fragile since if you refactor the Calculator constructor you will only find out at runtime.

So a better approach is an `InjectionFactory`, where you give it a Func that creates your calculator object. That Func is able to access the container, so can do named resolves. Here's a passing unit test that does what you want:

```csharp
[Test]
public void NamedDependenciesTest()
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IInputService, ConsoleInputService>();
    container.RegisterType<IOutputService, ConsoleOutputService>("Console");
    container.RegisterType<IOutputService, MessageBoxOutputService>("Window");

    container.RegisterType<ICalculator>("Cal1", new InjectionFactory((c) => new Calculator(c.Resolve<IInputService>(), c.Resolve<IOutputService>("Console"))));
    container.RegisterType<ICalculator>("Cal2", new InjectionFactory((c) => new Calculator(c.Resolve<IInputService>(), c.Resolve<IOutputService>("Window"))));

    // alternative setup with ResolvedParameter:
    //container.RegisterType<ICalculator, Calculator>("Cal1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IInputService)), new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IOutputService), "Console")));
    //container.RegisterType<ICalculator, Calculator>("Cal2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IInputService)), new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IOutputService), "Window")));

    var cal1 = container.Resolve<ICalculator>("Cal1");
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ConsoleOutputService>(cal1.OutputService);
    var cal2 = container.Resolve<ICalculator>("Cal2");
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<MessageBoxOutputService>(cal2.OutputService);
}

interface IInputService { }
interface IOutputService { }
interface ICalculator { IOutputService OutputService { get; } }
class ConsoleInputService : IInputService { }
class ConsoleOutputService : IOutputService { }
class MessageBoxOutputService : IOutputService { }
class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public Calculator(IInputService input, IOutputService output) { this.InputService = input; this.OutputService = output; }

    public IInputService InputService { get; private set; }
    public IOutputService OutputService { get; private set; }
}
```